# Linear transformations - Finding the representing matrix of a changed base.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T$ - linear transformation:

$$
T:R_3[x] \to R_3[x]
$$

$$
T(ax_2+bx+c) = (a+b+c)x^2 + (2a-(k^2-6)b+2c)x + a+b-c, k \in R
$$

$(1)$ For what values of $k$, $T$ is invertible?

$(2)$ calculate the representing matrix of $T$ in respect to the basis $B = (x^2-1,x+1,x)$.

**The question is for $(2)$ you can jump right to there or read how i did firstly $(1)$

---

$(1)$ We will start by looking at the coordinates of $T$ with respect to the standard basis:

$$
T = (a+b+c, 2a-(k^2-6)b+2c, a+b-c)
$$

Therefore we can calculate the representing matrix:

$$[T]_E = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1 \\ 2&6-k^2&2 \\ 1&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

In order for $T$ to be invertible we want that $rank([T]_E)$ will be full, namely the matrix will be invertible.

Therefore, we rank and get:

$$
[T]_E = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1 \\ 2&6-k^2&2 \\ 1&1&-1\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{RREF} \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1 \\ 0&4-k^2&0 \\ 0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore we want:

$$
4-k^2 \neq 0
$$

$$
\Downarrow
$$

$$
k \neq \pm 2
$$

We conclude that the matrix is invertible for $k$ values satisfies: 
$$
k \in R, k \neq \pm 2
$$

As we said, if he representing matrix is invertible $\Rightarrow$ the transformation in invertible.

### Question:

Let call the new basis $B' = (x^2-1,x+1,x)$

Now we get to the question. In order to find $T$ in respect to the new basis, should i calculate the transformation matrix from the standard basis to the new basis, call it $M$ and do:

$$
[T]_{B'} = M^{-1}[T]_BM
$$

Namely do that?

Call the standard basis $B = (x^2,x,1) = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$

$$
b_1' = (x^2-1) = 1x^2-0x-1*1
$$
$$
b_2' = (x+1) = 0x^2 + 1x + 1*1
$$
$$
b_3' = x = 0x^2 + 1x + 0
$$

$$
\Downarrow
$$

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\ -1&1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\Downarrow
$$

$$
M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 1&0&1 \\ -1&1&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore, we get:

$$
[T]_{B'} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 1&0&1 \\ -1&1&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1 \\ 2&6-k^2&2 \\ 1&1&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\ -1&1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Isnt there any easier way? calculating multiplication of 3 matrices especially with a variable $(k)$, is not nice.

Anyway, i get:

$$
[T]_{B'} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&2&1 \\ 2&2&2 \\ -2&6-k^2&4-k^2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

### #EDIT:

Another way that was suggested in the comments will be:

Find the value of thetransformation for the new basis and than represent it based on the new basis.

Remember: 
$$
B' = (x^2-1, x+1, x)
$$

$$
x^2 - 1 \Rightarrow a = 1,b=0,c=-1
$$

$$
x+1 \Rightarrow a=0,b=1,c=1
$$

$$
x \Rightarrow a=0,b=1,c=0
$$

$$
T(x^2 - 1) = 0x^2 + 0x + 2 = 2 = 2(x+1) - 2x
$$

$$
T(x+1) = a=0,b=1,c=1 = 2x^2 + (8-k^2)x + 2 = 2(x^2-1) + 2(x+1) + (6-k^2)x = 2x^2 + 2x + (6-k^2)x
$$

$$
T(x) = 1x^2 +(6-k^2)x + 1 = 1(x^2 -1) + 2(x+1) + (4-k^2)x
$$

Therfore, we get the same matrix for $[T]_B'$

Any corrections? better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not too much work to compute the matrix directly. Its columns are the images of the basis vectors, so: $$T(x^2-1) = 2 = 0(x^2-1)+2(x+1)-2x \\ T(x+1) = 2x^2+(8-k^2)x = 2(x^2-1)+2(x+1)+(6-k^2)x \\ T(x) = x^2+(6-k^2)x+1 = 1(x^2-1)+2(x+1)+(4-k^2)x,$$ therefore the matrix of $T$ relative to this basis is $$\begin{bmatrix}0&2&1\\2&2&2\\-2&6-k^2&4-k^2\end{bmatrix}.$$ It appears that you’ve made an error in your matrix multiplications. I get the same result by computing the matrix relative to the standard basis, which agrees with yours, and then applying a change of basis to it. That multiplication isn’t particularly tedious, I think, since it just involves simple sums and differences of matrix rows/columns.

Comment: How did you find the coefficients so easily? trial and error? And why the last one is 2(x+1) and not 1(x+1)?

Comment: The process is systematic. Only one basis vector involves $x^2$, so you can find its coefficient at a glance. Of the other two basis vectors, only one has a constant term, so after subtracting the contribution of $x^2-1$, you can again read the coefficient of $x+1$ from the expression. What’s left after subtracting that contribution is a multiple of $x$. Each step only affects one other term, so you can probably do this in your head. For $T(x)$ in particular, after subtracting $x^2-1$, the remaining constant term is $2$.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the help.